# PostgresSQL: Performance of using CASE inside WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

With PostgreSQL, I needed to define a query that would conditionally `SELECT` some data based on a parameter. In this statement, I have a condition that only needs to be evaluated only if another condition evaluates to `TRUE`.

To solve this, my first idea was to use a `CASE` inside a `WHERE`, which worked fine. For example, using a table `test_table` with columns `id`, `name`, and `value`:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM test_table
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN $1 > 10 THEN test_table.value > $1
        ELSE TRUE
    END
;
```

However, other peers suggested to use regular boolean logic instead, as it would perform faster. For example:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM test_table
WHERE
    (
        $1 <= 10
        OR test_table.value > $1
    )
;
```

After testing with around 100k rows and using `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, the speed difference seemed to average at about 1ms difference:

- With `CASE`: ~19.5ms Execution Time
- With Regular Booleans: ~18.5ms Execution Time

Question is: Is the second approach really faster? Or was my testing flawed, and thus the results incorrect?

Comment: With only 1ms difference I doubt documents a real difference. This is probably just a random difference because of other things. variation. How often did you run each query?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name. 20 times for each approach. Then calulated the average for those times.

Comment: I still think 1ms is not enough draw a verdict. Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers)`*** for each query (formatted text please, no screen shots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so much that not using the `case` is faster all the time.  The issue is that `case` prevents the optimizer from choosing different execution paths.  It basically says that the conditions *have* to be executed in order, because `case` expressions impose ordering.

With fewer options, the resulting query plan might be slower.

There are some cases where the execution order is an *advantage*.  This is particularly true when you know that some condition is very expensive to evaluate, so you want to be sure that other conditions are evaluated first:

```
where (case when x = 1 then true
            when <some expensive function> then true
       end)
```

could be more performant than:

```
where (x = 1) or <some expensive function>
```

(although in this simple example I would expect the Postgres compiler to be smart enough to do the right thing in the second case).

The second reason for avoiding `case` in a `where` clause is aesthetic.  There are already sufficient boolean operators to generate just about any condition you need -- so `case` is syntactic sugar that usually provides no additional nutrients